# How to remove repetition in output in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I have this code :

```
likes(ali, football). 
likes(ali, tennis). 
likes(ahmad, tennis). 
likes(ahmad, handball). 
likes(samir, handball). 
likes(samir, swimming). 
likes(khaled, horseriding).   

friends(P1, P2):-
    likes(P1, G1), likes(P2, G1), P1\=P2.
```

input is :

```
friends(X, Y)
```

output is

```
X = ali,
Y = ahmad
X = ahmad,
Y = ali
X = ahmad,
Y = samir
X = samir,
Y = ahmad
```

How can I remove this repetition if it's possible.

Comment: You can change `P1 \= P2` to `P1 < P2` (or `P1 @< P2`).

Comment: @TomasBy worked worked! thanks!

Comment: @TomasBy must be `@</2` for general terms. `</2` is for numeric arguments.

Comment: Note that the solution using `@</2` is not that good either, as it makes `friends(samir, ahmad)` false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add predicates that should be tested when a variable was bound: [when/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=when/2):

```
when(ground(X+Y), X @< Y), friends(X,Y).
```

Once there are no more free variables in the term `X+Y`, then ensure `X @< Y`:

```
?- when(ground(X+Y), X @< Y), test:friends(X,Y).
X = ahmad,
Y = ali ;
X = ahmad,
Y = samir ;
```

That is useful for your test, but generally speaking I don't think that the repetition needs to be removed.

Answer (score 2):

Since my similar [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53438104/1243762) has all of the explanation I will only give the code here.

```
friend(P3,P4) :-
    likes(P1,G1),
    likes(P2,G1),
    P1 \= P2,
    normalize(P1,P2,P3,P4).

normalize(P1,P2,P1,P2) :- P1 @> P2.

normalize(P1,P2,P2,P1) :- P1 @=< P2.

friends(List) :-
    setof((P1,P2), (P1,P2)^friend(P1,P2), List).
```

Example:

```
?- friends(List).
List = [(ali, ahmad),  (samir, ahmad)].
```