# Prolog, print employees with same names

Tags: prolog

This is my first time using Prolog.

I have employees:

```
 employee(eID,firstname,lastname,month,year).
```

I have units:

```
 unit(uID,type,eId).
```

I want to make a predicate

```
double_name(X).
```

that  prints the last names of the employees with the same first name in the unit X.

I am doing something like this :

```
double_name(X) :- 
  unit(X,_,_eID),
  employee(_eID,_firstname,_,_,_),
  _name = _firstname,
  employee(_,_name,_lastname,_,_),
  write(_lastname).
```

But it prints all the employees in the unit.

How can i print only the employees with the same name ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
unit(unit_01,type,1).
unit(unit_01,type,2).
unit(unit_01,type,3).

employee(1,mary,smith,6,1992).
employee(2,fred,jones,1,1990).
employee(3,mary,cobbler,2,1995).

double_name(Unit) :-
  unit(Unit,_,Eid_1),
  employee(Eid_1,Firstname,Lastname_1,_,_),
  unit(Unit,_,Eid_2),
  Eid_1 \= Eid_2,
  employee(Eid_2,Firstname,Lastname_2,_,_),
  write(Firstname),write(","),write(Lastname_1),nl,
  write(Firstname),write(","),write(Lastname_2).
```

Variables in Prolog typically start with an upper case letter, but starting them with and underscore is allowed, but not typical.

In `double_name/2` the predicates like

```
unit(Unit,_,Eid_1) 
employee(Eid_1,Firstname,Lastname_1,_,_)
```

are used to load the values from the facts into variables while pattern matching (via unification) that the bound variables match with the fact.

To ensure that a person is not compared with themselves.

```
Eid_1 \= Eid_2
```

and to make sure that two people have the same first name the same variable is used: `Firstname`.

The `write/1` and `nl/0` predicates just write the result to the screen.

Example:

```
?- double_name(unit_01).
mary,smith
mary,cobbler
true ;
mary,cobbler
mary,smith
true ;
false.
```

Notice that the correct answer is duplicated. This can be resolved.

See: [Prolog check if first element in lists are not equal and second item in list is equal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53437271/1243762)

and look at the use of `normalize/4` and `setof/3` in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53438104/1243762)

which I leave as an exercise for you.

Comment: It would be better to just use `Firstname` in both queries rather than having two variables and equating them post-facto.

Comment: @DanielLyons Thanks. Changed.